# File is not uploading in path folder magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I created a custom module for career form page. I added a attach resume field.When I select a file and click on submit button then filename is save to the database but file is not uploading in media/career folder.

Please see the below code for controller action :

```
public function careersaveAction() {     

$data=$this->getRequest()->getParams(); 

  $fileName = '';



                        $fileName       = $_FILES['resume_path']['name'];                       
                        $fileExt        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, ".") ,1));                       
                        $fileNamewoe    = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
                        $fileName       = preg_replace('/\s+', '', $fileNamewoe) . time() . '.' . $fileExt; 
                        $uploader       = new Varien_File_Uploader('resume_path');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc', 'docx','pdf', 'jpg', 'png', 'zip')); //add more file types you want to allow

                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'career';

                        if(!is_dir($path)){
                            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                        }
                        $uploader->save($path . DS, $fileName );

      $career = Mage::getModel("career/career")->setData($data);
         if($career->Save()){
         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess("Thank you for get in touch with us. We will contact you soon.");
         $this->_redirect('career/index/');

         } else {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("Sorry, your informations are not submitted this time. Request you to try again.");
$this->_redirect('career/index/');

         }

    }
}
```

Please see the code and tell me the solution for this.
Thanks!

Comment: did you add enctype="multipart/form-data" or its remain in form?

Comment: No, bcoz when i am adding enctype="multipart/form-data" then filename is also not saving in database

Comment: But file is uploaded in path folder but not in database but when i remove it then data is save in database but file is not uploading in path folder

Comment: the problem is solved ..................there will be some variable problem which is not getting thats why.

Comment: Have you checked file or directory permission where you trying to upload your files? Is there any .htaccess file in destination directory?

Comment: problem is solved........the problem is in image path.